# Draw an ellipse in Tikz-cd around diagram

Tags: tikz-cd

I want to draw an ellipse around three pairs of nodes in my diagram: (32), (78) and (56).

```
\begin{tikzcd}
1\arrow[bend right]{r} \arrow{d} 
&3 \arrow[bend right]{l} \arrow[bend left]{r} 
&2 \arrow[bend left]{l} \arrow[bend right]{r}  \arrow{d} 
&4   \arrow[bend right]{l} \\
7\arrow[bend right]{r}
&8 \arrow[bend right]{l} \arrow[bend left]{r}  \arrow{u}
&5 \arrow[bend left]{l} \arrow[bend right]{r} 
&6  \arrow[bend right]{l} \arrow{u} 
\end{tikzcd}
```

Here is a picture of the diagram that the above code outputs, with the dashed ellipses I would like superimposed on top:

[image: the dream, ovals around certain numbers]

Here is the best I have been able to do so far, using answers from elsewhere:

```
\[\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={\node[ellipse,draw,blue,fit={(tikz@f@1-3-1) (tikz@f@1-3-2)}]{};}]
1\arrow[bend right]{r} \arrow{d} 
&3 \arrow[bend right]{l} \arrow[bend left]{r} 
&2 \arrow[bend left]{l} \arrow[bend right]{r}  \arrow{d} 
&4   \arrow[bend right]{l} \\
7\arrow[bend right]{r}
&8 \arrow[bend right]{l} \arrow[bend left]{r}  \arrow{u}
&5 \arrow[bend left]{l} \arrow[bend right]{r} 
&6  \arrow[bend right]{l} \arrow{u} 
\end{tikzcd}\]
```

with the output:

[image: unsatisfactory ellipse location]

I cannot figure out how to get the ellipse snugly around the pairs.

It seems that perhaps a different tikz would work better, like tikz picture, but all of the diagrams in my paper are written in the same way, so I would rather not rewrite this just to get ellipses around the nodes, because then it likely will not match.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Don't ignore error messages. Your code will throw the error

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named tikz@f@1-3-1 is known.
```

Because the second number is the row number and third the column number. You have only two rows.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,fit}
\tikzset{
   dashellipse/.style={ellipse,draw,dashed,inner sep=0pt,blue,fit={#1}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
   execute at end picture={
     \node[dashellipse=(tikz@f@1-1-2)(tikz@f@1-1-3)]{};
     \node[dashellipse=(tikz@f@1-2-1)(tikz@f@1-2-2)]{};
     \node[dashellipse=(tikz@f@1-2-3)(tikz@f@1-2-4)]{};
}]
1 \arrow[bend right]{r} \arrow{d} 
 & 3 \arrow[bend right]{l} \arrow[bend left]{r} 
 & 2 \arrow[bend left]{l} \arrow[bend right]{r}  \arrow{d} 
 & 4 \arrow[bend right]{l} \\
7 \arrow[bend right]{r}
 & 8 \arrow[bend right]{l} \arrow[bend left]{r}  \arrow{u}
 & 5 \arrow[bend left]{l} \arrow[bend right]{r} 
 & 6 \arrow[bend right]{l} \arrow{u} 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, it gives the error for me: "Package pgf Error: No shape named tikz@f@1-2-4 is known." Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @D.Davis Does that exact code give you an error? It works fine here, with an up to date TeX Live 2017. Which version of TikZ and `tikz-cd` do you have? (Add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass`, compile, and look at the `*File list*` near the end of the `.log` file to find out.)

Comment: Is it possible to use this to draw ellipses around 3 or 4 nodes?

Comment: @MathStudent020 Sure, just add more nodes to the list, e.g. `\node[dashellipse=(tikz@f@1-1-2)(tikz@f@1-1-3)(tikz@f@1-1-4)]{};`

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={
    ellipse,draw,dashed,
    inner xsep=-1pt, blue,
    }}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={
    \node[mynode, fit={(\tikzcdmatrixname-1-2) (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-3)}]{};
    \node[mynode, fit={(\tikzcdmatrixname-2-1) (\tikzcdmatrixname-2-2)}]{};
    \node[mynode, fit={(\tikzcdmatrixname-2-3) (\tikzcdmatrixname-2-4)}]{};
    }]
1\ar[bend right]{r} \ar{d} 
&3 \ar[bend right]{l} \ar[bend left]{r} 
&2 \ar[bend left]{l} \ar[bend right]{r} \ar{d} 
&4 \ar[bend right]{l} \\
7\ar[bend right]{r}
&8 \ar[bend right]{l} \ar[bend left]{r} \ar{u}
&5 \ar[bend left]{l} \ar[bend right]{r} 
&6 \ar[bend right]{l} \ar{u}  
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. = Torbjørn T. and I answered at the same moment... He explained the error but I leave my answer because with `inner xsep=-1pt` the ellipses look better.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, it gives the error for me: "Package pgf Error: No shape named tikz@f@1-2-4 is known."

Comment: @D.Davis Is the matrix the same of my mwe? Or have you used yours?

Comment: @D.Davis Or have you some node empty? That error occurs: if you have only 1 row, or 3 columns,  or the node at the 2nd row and 4th column is empty.

Comment: Stumbled onto this solution while working on a different problem. The identifiers `tikz@f@n-r-c` should probably be replaced with `\tikzcdmatrixname-r-c` in case the diagram is not actually the first diagram in the document. This may be the cause of the error OP was getting. The fix comes from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405152/125871) by @Henri Menke.

Comment: @SandyG Corrected, thanks!