# Setting the name of matrix in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

*tikz-cd* wraps matrix creation as follows

```
\def\tikzcd@[#1]{%
  \tikzpicture[/tikz/commutative diagrams/.cd,every diagram,#1]%
  % ...
  \matrix[%
    % ...
    ]%
  \bgroup}
```

As such, there seems no way to name the matrix as created by the `tikzcd` environment. Is there a way to name the matrix, and still using the `tikzcd` environment?

The question arises out of the need to name cells of matrices. With the name of a matrix known, the cells could be conveniently referred to as `name-1-1`, for example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The name is already set and can be retrived from the macro `\tikzcdmatrixname`.  To further draw over your `tikzcd` matrix use `execute at end picture`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={
    \filldraw[red] (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[blue] (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-2) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[green] (\tikzcdmatrixname-2-1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[orange] (\tikzcdmatrixname-2-2) circle[radius=1pt];
  }]
  A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\
  C \ar[r]       & D \\
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1! Where can it be found in `tikz-cd` documentation? I searched but I didn't find it.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I was reading the source and found `\global\let\tikzcdmatrixname\tikzlastnode` in there i.e. it is not documented.  The `execute at end picture` trick on the other hand *is* documented.

Comment: I'll write to the authors asking to document `\tikzcdmatrixname`, thank you!

Comment: Nice the increasing string sizes: `3,4,5,6` to produce the diagonal alignment of node code. -)

Comment: This solution just saved me a lot of editing. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

The author of `tikz-cd` himself in person (Florêncio Neves) suggested to me to use `every matrix/.append style={name=...}` (don't forget the `append`, see 
[Torbjørn T.'s answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407304/101651)). This way you could name your matrix as you wish.

I also think it's possible to use `remember picture` and `overlay` instead of `execute at end picture`. Here an MWE with both cases:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[every matrix/.append style={name=mycd}, 
    execute at end picture={
    \filldraw[red] (mycd-1-1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[blue] (mycd-1-2) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[green] (mycd-2-1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[orange] (mycd-2-2) circle[radius=1pt];
    }]
    A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\
    C \ar[r]       & D 
\end{tikzcd}%

\begin{tikzcd}[every matrix/.append style={name=mycd}, remember picture]
    A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\
    C \ar[r]       & D 
\end{tikzcd}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \filldraw[red] (mycd-1-1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[blue] (mycd-1-2) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[green] (mycd-2-1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[orange] (mycd-2-2) circle[radius=1pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]