# every matrix/.style={name=...} option produces spurious spaces

Tags: spacing, tikz-cd

While I was answering [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405149/setting-the-name-of-matrix-in-tikz-cd), I realized that when the option `every matrix/.style={name=...}` is added to a `tikz-cd` environment, some spurious spaces appear, see the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
The difference between these commutative diagrams:

\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={
    \filldraw[red] (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[blue] (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-2) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[green] (\tikzcdmatrixname-2-1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[orange] (\tikzcdmatrixname-2-2) circle[radius=1pt];
  }]
  A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\
  C \ar[r]       & D \\
\end{tikzcd}%
\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={
    \filldraw[red] (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[blue] (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-2) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[green] (\tikzcdmatrixname-2-1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[orange] (\tikzcdmatrixname-2-2) circle[radius=1pt];
  }]
  A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\
  C \ar[r]       & D \\
\end{tikzcd}%

and the following two is only the \texttt{every matrix/.style=\{name=...\}} option, which produces some spurios spaces, as you can easily see:

\begin{tikzcd}[every matrix/.style={name=mycd}, 
    execute at end picture={
    \filldraw[red] (mycd-1-1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[blue] (mycd-1-2) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[green] (mycd-2-1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[orange] (mycd-2-2) circle[radius=1pt];
    }]
    A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\
    C \ar[r]       & D \\
\end{tikzcd}%
\begin{tikzcd}[every matrix/.style={name=mycd}, 
    execute at end picture={
    \filldraw[red] (mycd-1-1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[blue] (mycd-1-2) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[green] (mycd-2-1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[orange] (mycd-2-2) circle[radius=1pt];
    }]
    A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\
    C \ar[r]       & D \\
\end{tikzcd}%

Is there any \texttt{\%} missing somewhere?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `every matrix` style is defined as

```
every matrix/.style={/tikz/inner sep=+0pt},
```

and you redefine it completely, thus removing the `inner sep` setting, and I guess the default value of `0.333em` is used instead. So you want `every matrix/.append style`, to add to the style instead of redefining it. (Also, you probably want to remove the `\\` from the last row, which gives an empty row.)

Output, with bounding rectangle drawn:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
The difference between these commutative diagrams:

\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={
    \filldraw[red] (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[blue] (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-2) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[green] (\tikzcdmatrixname-2-1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[orange] (\tikzcdmatrixname-2-2) circle[radius=1pt];
    \draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
  }]
  A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\
  C \ar[r]       & D 
\end{tikzcd}%
\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={
    \filldraw[red] (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[blue] (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-2) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[green] (\tikzcdmatrixname-2-1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[orange] (\tikzcdmatrixname-2-2) circle[radius=1pt];
    \draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
  }]
  A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\
  C \ar[r]       & D 
\end{tikzcd}%

and the following two is only the \texttt{every matrix/.style=\{name=...\}} option, which produces some spurios spaces, as you can easily see:

\begin{tikzcd}[every matrix/.append style={name=mycd}, 
    execute at end picture={
    \filldraw[red] (mycd-1-1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[blue] (mycd-1-2) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[green] (mycd-2-1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[orange] (mycd-2-2) circle[radius=1pt];
    \draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    }]
    A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\
    C \ar[r]       & D 
\end{tikzcd}%
\begin{tikzcd}[every matrix/.append style={name=mycd},%
    execute at end picture={%
    \filldraw[red] (mycd-1-1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[blue] (mycd-1-2) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[green] (mycd-2-1) circle[radius=1pt];
    \filldraw[orange] (mycd-2-2) circle[radius=1pt];
    \draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    }]
    A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\
    C \ar[r]       & D 
\end{tikzcd}%

Is there any \texttt{\%} missing somewhere?
\end{document}
```

Comment: It was a trivial error of mine, then! Thank you!