# Label inside tikzcd square

Tags: tikz-cd

I have part of a diagram with tikzcd which looks like this:

```latex
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=20mm]
A\ar[rd,"a"] & \\
B\ar[rd,"b"]\ar[u,"b"] & C \\
& D\ar[u,"d"]
\end{tikzcd}
```

and produces the following

[image]

Now, I want to add a text in the middle of this diagram, and with the same inclination than it. The only way that I got to produce this, was to embed the tikzcd inside a tikzpicture:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=20mm]
      A\ar[rd,"a"] & \\
      B\ar[rd,"b"]\ar[u,"b"] & C \\
      & D\ar[u,"d"]
  \end{tikzcd}};
  \node[rotate=-25] {Text};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Is there any way to produce the same within the tikzcd environment?

Comment: OK, I see, and added a proposal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405152/121799) there is no need to nest `tikzpicture`s, which you are effectively doing when putting a `tikzcd` environment into a node of a `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}  
\[  \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=20mm,
  execute at end picture={
    \path (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-1) -- (\tikzcdmatrixname-2-1)
    coordinate[pos=0.5] (aux1)
    (\tikzcdmatrixname-2-2) -- (\tikzcdmatrixname-3-2)
    coordinate[pos=0.5] (aux2)
    (aux1) -- (aux2) node[midway,sloped]{Text};
  }]
      A\ar[rd,"a"] & \\
      B\ar[rd,"b"]\ar[u,"b"] & C \\
      & D\ar[u,"d"]
  \end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.

Comment: @AlejandroDC You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution from within `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=20mm]
A\ar[rd,"a"] \ar[rd, phantom, shift right=3.4ex, "\quad\text{Text}" marking]& \\
B\ar[rd,"b"]\ar[u,"b"] & C \\
& D\ar[u,"d"]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (a) my answer is "from within `tikz-cd`" as well and (b) is there a way to avoid the hard-coded distance in `shift right=3.4ex`?

Comment: @marmot:  I wrote `another solution from within tikz-cd`, not `another solution, from within tikz-cd`. (b) I don't know enough of tikz to say whether it's possible. It  would be possible if there is a way to determine the mid-points between A and B, and between C and D.

Comment: Yes, there are ways, but the most straightforward one may be either loading `calc` or doing something of the sort I did. BTW, you do not need two separate arrows, if you are fine with adding explicit dimensions you could just do `A\ar[rd,"a","\text{Text}" {sloped,below=1.5ex,xshift=0.75em}]`.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I added a phantom arrow, as you can guess, to have full control on the distance.