# Tikzcd pullback square issue

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-cd

I have a tikzcd diagram

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}
F \arrow[r] \arrow[d] 
& * \arrow[d] \\
X \arrow[r, "f"] & Y \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
```

which looks like this:

[image: Pullback square]

I wish to add a symbol which indicates that this is a pullback square. Having looked both [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/pushouts-and-pullbacks) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482822/label-inside-tikzcd-square), I have found the solution to create my own tikz-cd symbol, and insert that into the diagram.

The code for my symbol is this:

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]%
\draw (0,0) -- (1ex,0ex);%
\draw (1ex,0ex) -- (1ex,1ex);%
\end{tikzpicture}%
 }
```

This is basically the bottom and right hand edge of a square.

To add this symbol into the diagram, I am changing the code for the diagram to:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}
F \arrow[r] \arrow[d] 
\arrow[dr, phantom, "\foo{} " , very near start, color=black]
& * \arrow[d] \\
X \arrow[r, "f"] & Y \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
```

As far as I know, this should be creating an invisible arrow, and putting my symbol at its head. Indeed, something does appear, but its not my what I want:

[image]

What should appear is something like this (designed in MSpaint):

[image]

Which is the same thing except the symbol with the correct symbol.

What's going wrong? Should I be approaching this in a different way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your approach nests `tikzpicture`s. The standard way to avoid that is to [use `\savebox`es](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47377/121799).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newsavebox{\pullback}
\sbox\pullback{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\draw (0,0) -- (1ex,0ex);%
\draw (1ex,0ex) -- (1ex,1ex);%
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}
F \arrow[r] \arrow[d] 
\arrow[dr, phantom, "\usebox\pullback" , very near start, color=black]
& * \arrow[d] \\
X \arrow[r, "f"] & Y \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You defined your command with a parameter, which you did not use. Let's assume that there is a need for such parameters. Then `\savebox`es are unhandy. Therefore I add an alternative: a `path picture` with as many things fixed as you can think of. E.g. `-` is to say that there should not be an arrow, etc. (I understand that it is very unlikely that you want the symbol to be red, this is just to illustrate that parameters work here.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{pullback/.style={minimum size=1.2ex,path picture={
\draw[opacity=1,black,-,#1] (-0.5ex,-0.5ex) -- (0.5ex,-0.5ex) -- (0.5ex,0.5ex);%
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}
F \arrow[r] \arrow[d] 
\arrow[dr, phantom," " {pullback=red}, very near start, color=black]
& * \arrow[d] \\
X \arrow[r, "f"] & Y \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Why don't you simply insert the `\lrcorner` symbol?

```
 \documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd, amsmath, amssymb}%

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}
F \arrow[r] \arrow[d]
\arrow[dr, phantom, "\scalebox{1.5}{\color{IndianRed}$\lrcorner$}" , very near start, color=black]
& * \arrow[d] \\
X \arrow[r, "f"] & Y \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I should perhaps have stated - I don't like the way this looks and so am looking for alternatives

Comment: I don't see any difference with the other images, except perhaps in size. Would you have a link to what you'd like?

Comment: Size is indeed my problem.

Comment: And with  a `\scalebox` (please see my update)?

Comment: This indeed would be great - I have marked another as the answer already but this works well.

Answer (score 5):

Inside a `tikzpicture`, along a `path`, you can put not only `node` but also `pic`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bmr/.pic={
\draw (2mm,0)--++(-90:2mm)--++(180:2mm);
}]
\path
(0,0)     node (F) {$F$}
+(-45:.2) pic[scale=.8,red]{bmr}
+(0:1.5)  node (star) {$*$}
++(-90:1) node (X) {$X$}
+(0:1.5)  node (Y) {$Y$};
\draw[->] (F)--(star);
\draw[->] (F)--(X);
\draw[->] (X)--(Y) node[midway,above,scale=.6]{$f$};
\draw[->] (star)--(Y);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: can i do something similar using tikzcd instead of tikzpicture?