# Having arrows enter and leave from different parts of a node in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I am trying to get arrows to enter and leave different parts of a node in a particular diagram I'm writing in tikzcd. So far I have the following:

```
\begin{tikzcd} 
\makebox[1em][r]{$Long text 1$} \arrow[rr] \arrow[d] &    & 
\makebox[1em][l]{$Long text 2$} \arrow[d] \\
{A} \arrow[r] & {B} \arrow[r] & C
\end{tikzcd}
```

Which produces the following result:
[image]

So essentially I would like the arrow from "Long text 1" to "A" to start at the L and the arrow from "Long text 2" to "C" to start at the 2, while not changing the arrow going from "Long text 1" to "Long text 2".

Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define `start` style that use `to path` to set the starting anchor.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\tikzstyle{start}=[to path={(\tikztostart.#1) -- (\tikztotarget)}]
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzcd}[]
    \text{Long text 1} \arrow[rr] \arrow[d,start=205]
                  &               & \text{Long text 2} \arrow[d,start=335] \\
    {A} \arrow[r] & {B} \arrow[r] & C
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, would there be any way to make the middle arrow shorter as well, so that it is still a nice rectangle?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX-SE! You can do that using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405152/121799). I'm not sure, though, I personally would go for it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}  
\[  \begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={
    \draw[->] ([xshift=-4em]\tikzcdmatrixname-1-1.south) -- (\tikzcdmatrixname-2-1);
    \draw[->] ([xshift=4em]\tikzcdmatrixname-1-3.south) -- (\tikzcdmatrixname-2-3);
      }]
\makebox[1em][r]{Long text 1} \arrow[rr]  &    & 
\makebox[1em][l]{Long text 2} \\
{A} \arrow[r] & {B} \arrow[r] & C
  \end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]