# How to draw a commutative diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

Please I need the LaTeX code of the following diagram.

[image]

Comment: Look at the `tikz-cd` manual and examples on this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a just-do-it-for-me question. Please read the manual first, and ask only if you are stuck!

Comment: This question has a few subtle points that a beginner would not be able to accomplish. The present answers don't touch all of them.

Comment: @egreg Wouldn't it be better if the OP indicated what is missing instead of a third party? At least this is how I "If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question." interpret. Once the OP indicates what is missing, the question can be reopened. (Note that I did not vote to close the question.)

Comment: @egreg Yes, there may be something difficult and complicated to beginners. However, at least there should be some efforts shown here. For example, if the OP doesn't know how to draw the curve, he may draw a line and ask us to modify the line. We should never encourage people to ask us to draw figures whenever they need, for free.

Comment: In the current state, I don't agree with the reopeners.

Answer (score 2):

as starting point:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.1415692mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{tikzcd}
A \ar[r, "label"] 
  \ar[d, "label" ']  
        & B \ar[r, "label"] & C \ar[d,  "label"] \\
D       &                   & E \ar[ll, "label"] \\
\end{tikzcd}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\end{document}
```

[image]

for details see documentation for `tikz-cd`. package. You only need to replace node names and edges' labels with your math expressions.

Comment: add  `column sep=...` and `row sep=...` as option to `\begin{tikzcd}` . see documentation, page 6.

Answer (score 2):

In this question there is one somewhat nonstandard problem which is to have the text along a bent arrow in `tikz-cd`. This can be accomplished using `decorations.text` along with [`execute at end picture`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405152/121799).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=pi*1cm,row sep=pi*1cm,
execute at end picture={
\draw[<-,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,
raise=1ex,
text={|\small|change of variable}}}]  (\tikzcdmatrixname-2-1) 
to[bend left=15] (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-1);
  }
  ]
u \ar[r, "g(s)"]  & g(u) \ar[r, "G(s)=\int\limits_0^sg(r)\,\mathrm{d}r"] & 
        G(u) \ar[d,  "\psi(t)=\int\limits_0^r\mathrm{e}^{-G(s)}\,\mathrm{d}s"] \\
v=\varphi(u)       &                   & 
\psi(u) \ar[ll, "\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}~\text{w/}~\varphi'(s)>0" ',
"\varphi(s)=\psi^{-1}(s)"] \\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]