# Want to draw this commutative diagram

Tags: commutative-diagrams

Not a pro in Latex, struggling to draw this commutative diagram. Any help is appreciated. [image]

Comment: Perhaps you could try using the tikz-cd package. https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd?lang=en Try it and let us know where you get stuck.

Comment: For star see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490500/  (it is only similar). Also search for questions tagged as `tikz-cd`. Also reading of `tikz-cd` package will be helpful.

Comment: You can use general graph drawing as a starting point. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474634/116513

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We use the `tikz-cd`-package for this. If you are a beginner, you probably should have a look at [this](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de) online-editor.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep = huge, column sep = huge]
A \arrow[r, "\varphi_1"] \arrow[d, "\varphi_2", swap] \arrow[dd, bend right = 40, "\varphi_8", swap] & B \arrow[d, "\varphi_3"] \arrow[dd, bend left = 40, "\varphi_9"] \\
C \arrow[r, "\varphi_4"] \arrow[d, "\varphi_5", swap]                             & D \arrow[d, "\varphi_6"]                       \\
E \arrow[r, "\varphi_7", swap]                  & F                                
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]