# Commutative Diagram not working for slides

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams, slideshow

I asked this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503622/want-to-draw-this-commutative-diagram) some times ago and the given solution perfectly worked for me. Now I am trying to draw the same thing in a slide and it's not working.

Here's the code I used:

```
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Almost Complex Structure on a Riemann Surface}

\begin{itemize}

\item   <1-> So, we get a diagram: \\

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep = huge, column sep = huge]
T_p M \arrow[r, "J"] \arrow[d, "d\varphi_p", swap] \arrow[dd, bend right = 100, "d\psi_p", swap] & T_p M \arrow[d, "d\varphi_p"] \arrow[dd, bend left = 100, "d\psi_p"] \\

\mathbb{C} \arrow[r, "M_i"] \arrow[d, "d(\psi\circ\varphi^{-1})_0", swap]                             & \mathbb{C} \arrow[d, "d(\psi\circ\varphi^{-1})_0"]                       \\

\mathbb{C} \arrow[r, "M_i", swap]                  & \mathbb{C}                              

\end{tikzcd}\\

\end{center}

\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: Either add `[fragile]` after `\begin{frame}` or `,ampersand replacement=\&` after `column sep = huge`. In the second case, you need to replace all ampersands `&` by `\&` in your matrix. See e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/507508/194703) for more information.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat wow!!! worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat it would make more sense, I didn't see the link in your comment. You know the workings of the site so well after just one month, almost as if you are the reincarnation of some other animal :)

Comment: @Marijn Cats and some other Ti*k*Zlings insist on [being beings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/tikzlings/info).