# how to combine features of tikz-picture with tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees, tikz-cd

I drew a diagram in tikz-cd using the following

```
\begin{tikzcd}
    & A \arrow[r]  & B\arrow[loop above] & C\arrow[l]\\
    D\arrow[r] & E\arrow[loop above] &  & F\arrow[ul]\\
     & G\arrow[u] & H\arrow[ul] & \\
     & J\arrow[u] & & \\
\end{tikzcd}
```

However I want to draw a curve separating the two disconnected diagrams. For this, I wanted to use options of tikz-picture like declaring coordinates and drawing curves, in the same picture drawn by tikz-cd. Is that possible? I tried embedding tikz-cd inside tikz-picture

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzcd}
    & A \arrow[r]  & B\arrow[loop above] & C\arrow[l]\\
    D\arrow[r] & E\arrow[loop above] &  & F\arrow[ul]\\
     & G\arrow[u] & H\arrow[ul] & \\
     & J\arrow[u] & & \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for your suggestion to wrap the `tikzcd` environment in a `tikzpicture`. Please don't! This amounts to nesting `tikzpicture`, which is not supported and can lead to all sorts of complications.

I will assume that you are *not* looking for something like the example on the top of p. 13 of the `tikz-cd` manual. This allows you to embed matrices in the `tikzpicture` but it won't support the `\arrow` command (without further ado). That this, the following assumes that you do want to use the `\arrow` command. Then there are at least two ways to add plain Ti*k*Z code:

1. `execute at end picture`, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405152/121799) for an original post on this.
2. `remember picture`.

Both allow you to draw stuff, and to access nodes from the diagram. You may use either `alias` or `\tikzcdmatrixname-<row>-<column>`, which is the predefined node name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\subsection*{Method 1: \texttt{execute at end picture}}
\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={
\draw[-latex,red] ([yshift=1cm]A) to[out=45,in=170] ([yshift=1cm]C)
to[out=-10,in=45] (F);
\draw[blue] ([yshift=0.5em]D.north west) to[out=20,in=180] 
([yshift=1.5em]E.north) to[out=0,in=160] ([yshift=-0.5em]F.south east);}]
    & |[alias=A]|A \arrow[r]  & B\arrow[loop above] & |[alias=C]| C\arrow[l]\\
    |[alias=D]|D\arrow[r] & |[alias=E]| E\arrow[loop above] &  & |[alias=F]| F\arrow[ul]\\
     & G\arrow[u] & H\arrow[ul] & \\
     & J\arrow[u] & & \\
\end{tikzcd}

\subsection*{Method 2: \texttt{remember picture}}
\begin{tikzcd}[remember picture]
    & |[alias=A]|A \arrow[r]  & B\arrow[loop above] & |[alias=C]| C\arrow[l]\\
    |[alias=D]| D\arrow[r] & |[alias=E]| E\arrow[loop above] &  & |[alias=F]| F\arrow[ul]\\
     & G\arrow[u] & H\arrow[ul] & \\
     & J\arrow[u] & & \\
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[-latex,red] ([yshift=1cm]A) to[out=45,in=170] ([yshift=1cm]C)
to[out=-10,in=45] (F);
\draw[blue] ([yshift=0.5em]D.north west) to[out=20,in=180] 
([yshift=1.5em]E.north) to[out=0,in=160] ([yshift=-0.5em]F.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are more familiar with `calc` (instead of the `yshift`s) this will also work provided you load the library. As you can see, `overlay` has the slight disadvantage that the bounding box does not get adjusted, but may be argued to be less "hacky".

Comment: thanks. Can I draw a curve between, let's say at some unmarked point right above D and some unmarked point below F, so that two disconnected diagrams are separated by the curve? In tikz-picture, I could specify the coordinates of those points and draw a bent curve between the points. Can you do that on top of the matrix-based picture created by tikz-cd?