# Cross over of arrows in a complex diagram

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-matrix

[image]I have drawn a diagram using tikzpicture, but it has arrows crossing over each other.  How do I keep the Horizontal arrows in each level intact and break the other arrows at the point of intersection?

Here is my code:

```
%\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsxtra}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,shapes.geometric,trees,matrix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{caption}



\begin{document}






\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=1.6cm,
    column sep=0.4cm]{
    &&Level(1,3)&&&&\\
     &Level(2,2)&Level(2,3)&& Level(2,5)&&Level(2,7)\\
     &&Level(3,3)&& Level(3,5)&&Level(3,7)\\
      Level(4,1)&Level(4,2)&& Level(4,4)&&Level(4,6)&  \\
      &Level(5,2)&& Level(5,4)&&Level(5,6)& \\
       Level(6,1)&& Level(6,3)&& Level(6,5)&&\\
        Level(7,1) && Level(7,3)&& Level(7,5)&&\\};
  \path[-stealth]
(m-7-1) edge (m-7-3) edge (m-6-1)

(m-7-3) edge (m-7-5) 
        edge (m-6-3)

(m-7-5) edge (m-6-5) 
        edge (m-5-6)

(m-6-1) edge (m-6-3) 
        edge (m-4-1)

(m-6-3) edge (m-6-5) 
        edge (m-4-4)

(m-6-5) edge (m-4-6)
(m-5-2) edge (m-5-4) 
        edge (m-4-2)
        edge (m-3-3)

(m-5-4) edge (m-4-4) 
        edge (m-5-6)
        edge (m-3-5)
(m-5-6) edge (m-3-7)
(m-4-2) edge (m-4-4) 
        edge (m-2-2) 
        edge (m-2-3)

(m-4-4) edge (m-4-6) 
        edge (m-2-5)

(m-3-3) edge (m-2-3) 
        edge (m-3-5)

 (m-3-5) edge (m-3-7)
 (m-2-2) edge (m-1-3)
 (m-2-3) edge (m-1-3)
 (m-2-5) edge (m-2-7)
 ;

\path[>=stealth,-,thick]
(m-7-1) edge [double, minimum width=3cm] (m-5-2)
(m-6-1) edge [double, minimum width=3cm] (m-4-2)
(m-5-6) edge [double, minimum width=3cm] (m-4-6)
(m-4-1) edge [double, minimum width=3cm] (m-2-2)
(m-4-6) edge [double, minimum width=3cm] (m-2-7)
(m-3-5) edge [double, minimum width=3cm] (m-2-5)
(m-3-7) edge [double, minimum width=3cm] (m-2-7)
(m-2-3) edge [double, minimum width=3cm] (m-2-5)
;
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard trick for this is to draw a thick white line underneath, which can be achieved with `preaction`. This answer comes with a style `on top`, which can be used like `(m-6-5) edge[on top] (m-4-6)`. You need to draw the topmost connections last. At the moment, the default line widths of the white lines is `4pt` but you can adjust them to your needs.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[on top/.style={preaction={draw=white,-,line width=#1}},
on top/.default=4pt]
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=1.6cm,
    column sep=0.4cm]{
    &&Level(1,3)&&&&\\
     &Level(2,2)&Level(2,3)&& Level(2,5)&&Level(2,7)\\
     &&Level(3,3)&& Level(3,5)&&Level(3,7)\\
      Level(4,1)&Level(4,2)&& Level(4,4)&&Level(4,6)&  \\
      &Level(5,2)&& Level(5,4)&&Level(5,6)& \\
       Level(6,1)&& Level(6,3)&& Level(6,5)&&\\
        Level(7,1) && Level(7,3)&& Level(7,5)&&\\};
  \path[-stealth]
(m-7-1) edge (m-7-3) edge (m-6-1)

(m-7-3) edge (m-7-5) 
        edge (m-6-3)

(m-7-5) edge (m-6-5) 
        edge (m-5-6)

(m-6-1) edge (m-4-1)

(m-6-3) edge (m-6-5) 

(m-5-4) edge (m-4-4) 

(m-5-2) edge (m-5-4) 
        edge (m-4-2)
        edge (m-3-3)

(m-5-4)   edge (m-5-6)
        edge (m-3-5)
(m-5-6) edge (m-3-7)
(m-4-2)  edge (m-2-2) 
        edge (m-2-3)



(m-3-3) edge (m-2-3) 
        edge (m-3-5)

 (m-3-5) edge (m-3-7)
 (m-2-2) edge (m-1-3)
 (m-2-3) edge (m-1-3)
 (m-2-5) edge (m-2-7)
(m-4-2) edge[on top] (m-4-4) 
(m-4-4) edge[on top] (m-4-6) 
(m-6-5) edge[on top] (m-4-6)
(m-4-4) edge[on top] (m-2-5)
(m-6-3) edge[on top] (m-4-4)
 ;

\path[>=stealth,-,thick]
(m-7-1) edge [double] (m-5-2)
(m-6-1) edge [double] (m-4-2)
(m-5-6) edge [double] (m-4-6)
(m-4-1) edge [double] (m-2-2)
(m-3-5) edge [double] (m-2-5)
(m-3-7) edge [double] (m-2-7)
(m-2-3) edge [double] (m-2-5)
(m-4-6) edge [double,on top=5pt] (m-2-7)
;
\path[-stealth] (m-6-1) edge[on top] (m-6-3) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

@egreg called this code "awkward". The IMHO most redundant thing, however, is IMHO that one has to add the position of the entry by hand (but I do not like to use words like "awkward"). In any case, this can be made as easily as defining a style

```
level/.style={
execute at begin node={\text{Level}(\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)}
}
```

which gets used in the following code, which also has some loops to draw the arrows.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[on top/.style={preaction={draw=white,-,line width=#1}},
on top/.default=4pt,level/.style={
execute at begin node={\text{Level}(\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)}
}]
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,nodes=level,row sep=1.6cm,
    column sep=0.4cm]{
    &&{}&&&&\\
     &{}&{}&& {}&&{}\\
     &&{}&& {}&&{}\\
      {}&{}&& {}&&{}&  \\
      &{}&& {}&&{}& \\
       {}&& {}&& {}&&\\
        {} && {}&& {}&&\\};
\path[-stealth] 
 (m-6-1) edge (m-4-1) (m-4-2) edge (m-2-2) (m-2-3) edge (m-1-3)
 (m-4-2) edge (m-2-3) (m-5-2) edge (m-3-3) 
 (m-5-4) edge (m-3-5) (m-7-5) edge (m-5-6) (m-5-6) edge (m-3-7)
 (m-2-2) edge (m-1-3);
\path[-stealth,every edge/.append style={on top}]  
foreach \Y [count=\Z] in {3,5,7}{ 
  foreach \X in {1,3,5}
 {(m-\Y-\the\numexpr\X+3-\Z\relax) edge (m-\the\numexpr\Y-1\relax-\the\numexpr\X+3-\Z\relax)
 \ifnum\X<5
 (m-\Y-\the\numexpr\X+3-\Z\relax) edge (m-\Y-\the\numexpr\X+5-\Z\relax)
 \ifnum\the\numexpr\Y*10+\X=31
 \else
 (m-\the\numexpr\Y-1\relax-\the\numexpr\X+3-\Z\relax) edge (m-\the\numexpr\Y-1\relax-\the\numexpr\X+5-\Z\relax)
 \fi
 \fi
 }} (m-4-4) edge (m-2-5) (m-6-3) edge (m-4-4);
 \path[thick,every edge/.append style={double,on top=5pt}] 
  (m-4-1) edge (m-2-2) (m-6-1) edge (m-4-2) (m-7-1) edge (m-5-2)
  (m-2-3) edge (m-2-5) (m-2-7) edge (m-3-7)
  (m-2-7) edge (m-4-6) (m-4-6) edge (m-6-5);
\path[-stealth,every edge/.append style={on top}]  (m-6-1) edge (m-6-3); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This information, together with [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405152/121799), allows one to simplify egreg's answer and to correct the arrows there (such that there is a 3D impression).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\newcommand{\level}{\text{level}(\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.5em,row sep=large,arrows={crossing over},
execute at end picture={
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \path[->] (\tikzcdmatrixname-6-2) edge (\tikzcdmatrixname-6-4)
 (\tikzcdmatrixname-6-4) edge (\tikzcdmatrixname-6-6)
 (\tikzcdmatrixname-4-5) edge (\tikzcdmatrixname-4-7);
\end{scope}}]
&&
\level
\\ \\
&
\level \arrow[uur] &
\level \arrow[uu] \arrow[rr,thick,equals] &&
\level \arrow[rr] \arrow[ddl,leftarrow] &&
\level \arrow[ddl,thick,equals]
\\
&&
\level \arrow[u] \arrow[ddl,leftarrow] &&
\level \arrow[u,thick,equals]  \arrow[ddl,leftarrow] &&
\level \arrow[u,thick,equals]
\\
\level \arrow[uur,thick,equals] &
\level \arrow[uu] \arrow[rr] \arrow[uur] &&
\level \arrow[rr] \arrow[ddl,leftarrow] &&
\level \arrow[ddl,leftarrow]
\\
&
\level \arrow[u] \arrow[ddl,leftarrow] &&
\level \arrow[u]  &&
\level \arrow[u,thick,equals] \arrow[uur]
\\
\level \arrow[uu] \arrow[uur,thick,equals] \arrow[rr] &&
\level \arrow[rr] &&
\level
\\
\level \arrow[u] \arrow[rr] &&
\level \arrow[u] \arrow[rr] &&
\level \arrow[u] \arrow[uur]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

With `crossing over`, arrows that are drawn later, erase part of the arrows they cross.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\level}{\mathrm{Level}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.5em,row sep=large,arrows={crossing over}]
&&
\level(1,3)
\\ \\
&
\level(2,2) \arrow[uur] &
\level(2,3) \arrow[uu] \arrow[rr,thick,equals] &&
\level(2,5) \arrow[rr] \arrow[ddl,leftarrow] &&
\level(2,7) \arrow[ddl,thick,equals]
\\
&&
\level(3,3) \arrow[u] \arrow[rr] \arrow[ddl,leftarrow] &&
\level(3,5) \arrow[u,thick,equals] \arrow[rr] \arrow[ddl,leftarrow] &&
\level(3,7) \arrow[u,thick,equals]
\\
\level(4,1) \arrow[uur,thick,equals] &
\level(4,2) \arrow[uu] \arrow[rr] \arrow[uur] &&
\level(4,4) \arrow[rr] \arrow[ddl,leftarrow] &&
\level(4,6) \arrow[ddl,leftarrow]
\\
&
\level(5,2) \arrow[u] \arrow[rr] \arrow[ddl,leftarrow] &&
\level(5,4) \arrow[u] \arrow[rr] &&
\level(5,6) \arrow[u,thick,equals] \arrow[uur]
\\
\level(6,1) \arrow[uu] \arrow[uur,thick,equals] \arrow[rr] &&
\level(6,3) \arrow[rr] &&
\level(6,5)
\\
\level(7,1) \arrow[u] \arrow[rr] &&
\level(7,3) \arrow[u] \arrow[rr] &&
\level(7,5) \arrow[u] \arrow[uur]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can this be achieved in tikzpicture environment ? Also the figure is going outside the specified area of the generated pdf (using `amsart` documentclass), what to do?

Comment: @user149418 Using `matrix of math nodes` results in worse quality. About the size, I'm afraid that the only option is scaling.

Comment: I think the connection between (3,5) and (3,7) should be below (4,6) -- (2,7), likewise for (5,4) -- (5,6) vs. (6,5) -- (4,6). Also I do not think "matrix of math nodes esults in worse quality" is a true statement because tikz-cd precisely uses such a matrix.

Comment: @marmot In my experience the arrows are better directed with `\arrow` syntax. About the connections you mention, I followed the OP's preference, but I agree that it would be better as you propose.

Comment: "better directed" as compared to what? The `\arrow` command can be certainly looked up and used in "plain" Ti*k*Z, too. But of course I agree that for many purposes `tikz-cd` is more convenient (but this convenience backfires once one wants to do some "nonstandard" thing).

Comment: @marmot The rectangle shape for nodes is different. Here the nodes have the same height and width; the difference is apparent when there are different height, depth and width.

Comment: @egreg Sure, but you can always load the `cd` library which does have the `asymmetric rectangle` shape. I believe that it is mainly a matter of wording. Since `tikz-cd` is entirely based on `tikz`, there is nothing that you can't only do in `tikz-cd` but not in `tikz`. Similar comments apply e.g. to `smartdiagram`, like `tikz-cd` this is a great package, and really super convenient to use. However, everything that can be done with either of these packages can be done with "plain" Ti*k*Z, too, yet may require more keystrokes.

Comment: @marmot While you are right about the library, I find the syntax of `tikz-cd` not only “more convenient”. Your code is awkward and really difficult to maintain.

Comment: @egreg I find "awkward" a bit out of the place, this is not the wording that we should use, and this is not "my code". "My code" is the `on top` style, which is not awkward at all, and the above example allows one to retain full control over the outcome, something your suggestion can only achieve with much more efforts because the arrows get drawn in the order you place the commands. The code that you call "awkward", on the other hand, allows you to retain full control without any hack like `execute at end picture`.