# Tikzcd in beamer not working

Tags: beamer, tikz-cd, texworks

Currently I am trying to create a presentation with `tikzcd` using the TeXWorks Editor. Apparently, my computer does not recognize the command `\arrow` in the way I would need it to work with `tikzcd` (only a theory). Frankly speaking, it looks like my computer has problems with the `tikzcd` package at all.

This is working (well, if you want to call this working...)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[width=2.18cm]{PaloAlto}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{tikz, tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Not important}
\framesubtitle{Neither important}

$\begin{tikzcd}
\end{tikzcd}$

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But as soon as I insert something marginal useful (e.g. `A&B`, while a single `A` is working...), I get an *undefined control sequence* referring to `\end{frame}`. I want to include something like this

[image]

> I feel like I missing an important point, even though I copied the code given above straight from [here](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf). What could be wrong and more importantly: how do I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions of this type have been asked here before, but I could not find any answer with an explanation (which is most likely my fault). Anyway, here we go. In section **8 Creating Frames** of the `beamer` manual version 3.56 it is stated that (I highlighted the important part)

> The environment contents can be normal LATEX text, but may not contain
>   \verb commands or verbatim environments or *any environment that
>   changes the character codes*, unless the fragile option is given.

It also says on p. 61

> If a frame contains fragile text, different internal mechanisms are
>   used to typeset the frame to ensure that inside the frame the
>   character codes can be reset. The price of switching to another
>   internal mechanism is that either you cannot use overlays or an
>   external file needs to be written and read back (which is not always
>   desirable).

In any case, since `tikz-cd` does change some character codes, we need to add `fragile`. (As a rule of thumb, whenever something does not work in `beamer` which works fine elsewhere, it is worthwhile adding the `fragile` key and check whether or not this solves the problem. Some of the drawbacks of using `fragile` are discussed in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136240).)

I also used the opportunity to typeset the diagram, in which the `execute at end picture` key is used to connect the two edge labels, which attained names with the `alias` key.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[width=2.18cm]{PaloAlto}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Not important}
\framesubtitle{Neither important}
$\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={
\path (F) edge[double equal sign distance, -Implies,"$\omega$",
shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt] (G);}]
\mathcal{C} \arrow[r,bend left,"F" {alias=F}]
\arrow[r,bend right,"G" {swap,alias=G}]& \mathcal{D}
\\
\end{tikzcd}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: It has been suggested that the ampersand is the problem. I disagree with that statement. E.g.

```
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{The ampersand per se is not the problem} 
\begin{tabular}{ccc} 
a & b & c\\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{frame}
```

does work. It is the line `\catcode\`\&=13`that can be found in`tikz.code.tex`. It is true, though, that ampersand replacement is another way to solve the problem. I also want to add that I was using`execute at end picture`for a reason. Even though there are seemingly simpler ways, they do not allow you to control the order in which the arrows are placed because`tikz-cd` collects them internally and draws them in an order that we cannot control. Here it does not matter, but you can find [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497037) an example where it does.

Comment: Again, thank you! I'll wait before accepting your answer to see if someone else has some improvements to offer or even an alternative :)

Comment: @mrtaurho What kind of improvement are you after? To me the diagram looks fine (also because you do not overload it), what I would probably do is to make it larger, e.g. `\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=6em,execute at end picture={
\path (F) edge[double equal sign distance, -Implies,"$\omega$",
shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt] (G);}]
\mathcal{C} \arrow[r,bend left,"F" {alias=F}]
\arrow[r,bend right,"G" {swap,alias=G}]& \mathcal{D}
\\
\end{tikzcd}\]`, which also uses an equation environment. (I use `fragile` all the time and there is IMHO no real downside to it.)

Comment: It has been suggested that the ampersand is the problem. I disagree with that statement. E.g. `\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The ampersand per se is not the problem}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
 a & b & c\\
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}` does work. It is the line `\catcode\`\&=13` that can be found in `tikz.code.tex`. It is true, though, that `ampersand replacement` is another way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known problem: when a `tikzcd` is inside the argument to another command, `&` cannot be used; there's a handy workaround, though.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[width=2.18cm]{PaloAlto}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{tikz, tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Not important}
\framesubtitle{Neither important}

\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=4em]
\mathcal{C} \arrow[r, bend left=30, "F"{name=U}]
\arrow[r, bend right=30, "G"'{name=D}]
\& \mathcal{D}
\arrow[Rightarrow, from=U, to=D,shorten=4pt,"\omega"]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, but using `xy` package (`xymatrix`), is there the same problem?

Comment: @Sebastiano No, as far as I know.