# Centering commutativity arrow (arrow not showing)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I have the following diagram where I am using the \tikzcdmatrixname command to place the commutativity arrow, and using the "at end of picture" trick, but the arrow is not showing up. These tricks come [from this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405149/setting-the-name-of-matrix-in-tikz-cd). I'm not sure what is happening... How can I get the arrow centred in the middle of the diagram? MWE below.

[image]

```
    \documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture=%
    {
        \arrow[to path={(\tikzcdmatrixname-1-3) node[midway,scale=1.5] {$\circlearrowleft$}(\tikzcdmatrixname-3-3)}];
    }]
    && {\pi_1(A_{\alpha})} \\
    {\pi_1((A_{\alpha} \cap A_{\beta})} &&&& {\pi_1(X)} \\
    && {\pi_1(A_{\beta})}
    \arrow["{(I_{\alpha \beta})_*}", hook, from=2-1, to=1-3]
    \arrow["{(I_{\beta \alpha})_*}"', hook, from=2-1, to=3-3]
    \arrow[hook, from=1-3, to=2-5]
    \arrow[hook, from=3-3, to=2-5]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think, this is what you're after:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd, mathabx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={
        \path(\tikzcdmatrixname-1-3)  -- (\tikzcdmatrixname-3-3) node[midway,scale=1.5] {$\circlearrowleft$};
    }]
    & & {\pi_1(A_{\alpha})} & & \\
    {\pi_1((A_{\alpha} \cap A_{\beta})} & & & & {\pi_1(X)} \\
    & & {\pi_1(A_{\beta})} & & 
    \arrow["{(I_{\alpha \beta})_*}", hook, from=2-1, to=1-3]
    \arrow["{(I_{\beta \alpha})_*}"', hook, from=2-1, to=3-3]
    \arrow[hook, from=1-3, to=2-5]
    \arrow[hook, from=3-3, to=2-5]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear how arrow in middle of diagram look. Is this vertical straight arrow or is  arc as guess @Jasper Habicht in his answer.

For both case the code can be much simpler as OP's MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                bending}
\tikzset{C/.style={circle, minimum size=8mm,
                   node contents={},
                   append after command={\pgfextra{%
        \draw[-{Straight Barb[flex']}](\tikzlastnode.150) arc (150:450:4mm);}
                }}
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
    &   \pi_1(A_{\alpha})
        \ar[dr, hook]
        \ar[dd,shorten >=3mm, shorten <=3mm]         
                        &                       \\
\pi_1(A_{\alpha} \cap A_{\beta})
\ar[ru, "{(I_{\beta\alpha})_*}", hook]
\ar[rd, "{(I_{\alpha\beta})_*}"', hook]
    &                   &   \pi_1(A_{\beta})    \\
    &   \pi_1(A_{\beta})
        \ar[ur, hook]   &
     \end{tikzcd}

    \begin{tikzcd}
    &   \pi_1(A_{\alpha}) 
        \ar[dr, hook, ""name=U]
                        &                       \\
\pi_1(A_{\alpha} \cap A_{\beta})
\ar[ru, "{(I_{\beta\alpha})_*}", hook]
\ar[rd, "{(I_{\alpha\beta})_*}"', hook,""name=D]
\ar[to path={(U) node[pos=.6,xshift=1.5em,C] (D)}] {}
    &                   &   \pi_1(A_{\beta})    \\
    &   \pi_1(A_{\beta})
        \ar[ur, hook]   &   
     \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]