Tikz-cd problem: "Package pgf Error: No shape named `tikz@f@1-2-1' is known" error
I want to put an ellipse around two nodes of a tikz-cd diagram and am using the approach described in How to put ellipses around nodes in tikz-cd diagrams several times in one document.
The minimal example shows that when a correctly-compiling tikz-cd diagram that references nodes using the tikz@f@x-y-z syntax is preceded by another tikz-cd diagram compilation fails with the error "Package pgf Error: No shape named `tikz@f@1-2-1' is known".
To duplicate this behaviour first run the code as given, which compiles correctly. Then uncomment the first tikz-cd diagram and compile again to generate the error. It seems that the first diagram sets something in the background, but I am clueless as to what it is or how to avoid this problem.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

%\[
%\begin{tikzcd}
%A
%\end{tikzcd}
%\]

% The following compiles correctly, 
% but if above is uncommented the compilation fails with error
% ! Package pgf Error: No shape named `tikz@f@1-2-1' is known

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={%
\node[ellipse, draw, fit=(tikz@f@1-2-1) (tikz@f@1-2-3)] {};}]
& \bullet \ar[dl] \ar[dr] \\
\bullet & & \bullet
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}



welcome! why are you putting it inside a maths environment?

you need to change the first number from 1 to 2, but I suspect you are not really supposed to use these names - they are probably for internal use by the package.

Thanks! Yes, putting it is a maths environment is unnecessary, but it does not make any difference whether I do that or not. My referencing of matrix elements seems to be standard when using the "execute at end picture" option (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/697201). What I cannot understand is why I need to change the first number to 2. If I put another tikz diagram before the other two, then I find that I have to change the first number to 3. Clearly this is a problem, since the diagram that I want to use sits somewhere between a multitude of other tikz diagrams.

I have now solved my problem by naming the nodes around which I want to draw the ellipse using the |[]| syntax, and then used these names to reference the nodes instead of using the tikz@f@x-y-z syntax. I shall amend my post to reflect both the problem and the solution. Thanks for your pointing out the source of my problem.

please don't edit the solution into your question. you are welcome to post it as another answer.

Oops, I've already done that. Please forgive both the ignorance and the over-enthusiasm of a newcomer. Should I revert my post to the original version?

please, yes. otherwise somebody else will do it. but it is better if you do it. but no worries. the site is a bit confusing at first. (was to me anyway. pretty sure )

I have now done so.

You are relying on internal names for nodes. This is not a great idea because such implementation details can easily change when a package is updated, breaking your existing documents.
Moreover, in this case you would have to keep track of the number of diagrams in your document and adjust the first number of each reference accordingly. That is, tikz@f@1-... applies to only the first such diagram. The next uses tikz@f@2-... and so on.
I can't find a nice solution to this which does not make the code more cumbersome. The simplest, but not the most robust, approach would be to use \tikzcdmatrixname-... which will automatically pick up the prefix appropriate to the current diagram, regardless of where it comes in the document. However, this macro does not seem to be in the user documentation so, although it does not include the telltale @, the author may regard it as internal and subject to change without notice.
It does, however, work well with the current version of the package.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzcd}
      A
    \end{tikzcd}
  \end{center}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={%
          \node[ellipse, draw, fit=(\tikzcdmatrixname-2-1) (\tikzcdmatrixname-2-3)] {};
        },
      ]
      & A \ar[dl] \ar[dr] \\
    B & & C
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}

\end{document}

What one might like here would be an option to name the internal matrix of nodes via an option provided by tikz-cd. This is would be easy to add because the code is already set up to check whether the internal name is defined and to use the existing name if it is. This is supported behaviour as the documentation includes at least one example which relies on this. However, the envisaged use appears to be restricted to use of the package within a tikzpicture, where \matrix is invoked explicitly. I think this would make a good feature request (unless I've missed something in the documentation explaining a supported way to achieve the same result).

Thanks, this helped me a lot. Also to search for another way of referencing the nodes in a more robust way, as demonstrated in my answer below.

While I believe that the \tikzcdmatrixname solution is valid enough, even if the macro name is not documented, I want to highlight some other approaches.

We can give the matrix a name or an alias which we can use instead of \tikzcdmatrixname.
We can use \tikzlastnode which TikZ sets after a node, here we use the append after command hook on the matrix. In my solution via the Ellipse Around key, the prefix \tikzlastnode- is set so you only have to provide <row>-<column>.
We can use the TikZ-CD's own \arrow functionality by setting a to path that simply places a node.

Code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}
\tikzcdset{
  Ellipse Around/.style={
    every matrix/.append style={
      append after command={\bgroup
        node[shape=ellipse, draw, name prefix=\tikzlastnode-, fit={#1}]{}
      \egroup}}},
  Ellipse From To/.style={
    to path={node[shape=ellipse, draw, fit=(\tikztostart)(\tikztotarget)]{}}},
  matrix name/.style={every matrix/.append style={name={#1}}},
  matrix alias/.style={every matrix/.append style={alias={#1}}}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[
  execute at end picture={%
    \node[ellipse, draw, fit=(\tikzcdmatrixname-2-1)(\tikzcdmatrixname-2-3)] {};
  }]
        & \bullet \ar[dl] \ar[dr]           \\
\bullet &                         & \bullet
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[
  matrix name = matrixname,
  execute at end picture={%
    \node[ellipse, draw, fit=(matrixname-2-1) (matrixname-2-3)] {};
  }]
        & \bullet \ar[dl] \ar[dr]           \\
\bullet &                         & \bullet
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[Ellipse Around=(2-1)(2-3)]
        & \bullet \ar[dl] \ar[dr]           \\
\bullet &                         & \bullet
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
                                 & \bullet \ar[dl] \ar[dr]           \\
\bullet \ar[rr, Ellipse From To] &                         & \bullet
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}


Thanks! Your suggestions are very useful, and I learnt much from them.

I have found another solution which should be robust with respect to changes in the tikz-cd package. Name the relevant nodes using the |[alias]| syntax described in the tikz-cd manual, as shown in the third tikz figure of the expanded minimal example, and use these names to reference the nodes around which the ellipse is to be drawn.
To demonstrate both the original problem and this solution first run the code as given, which compiles correctly. Uncomment the first tikz-cd diagram and compile again to generate the error. Then comment the second diagram with the tikz@f@x-y-z syntax and find that the third diagram, which references the named nodes, compiles correctly in the presence of the first diagram.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

%\begin{tikzcd}
%A
%\end{tikzcd}

% The following compiles correctly, 
% but if above is uncommented the compilation fails with error
% ! Package pgf Error: No shape named `tikz@f@1-2-1' is known

\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={%
\node[ellipse, draw, fit=(tikz@f@1-2-1) (tikz@f@1-2-3)] {};}]
& A \ar[dl] \ar[dr] \\
B & & C
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={%
\node[ellipse, draw, fit=(B) (C)] {};}]
& A \ar[dl] \ar[dr] \\
|[alias=B]| B  & & |[alias=C]| C
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}


thanks for editing!
